# Play a video in a Windows Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am making a program and wanted to play a video when I press the one of the buttons, but I have no ideia how to make this, I wanted to play the video and display a number that is going to be randomly generated

I tried using the System.Media library but I couldn't find a player for video, just for sounds

Comment: The link and information provided by wordlesssafe are completely correct, please check to see if it can help you, if you have any questions, please update the question and comment below, I will continue to follow up. Please mark it if useful。

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a player component for WinForms, check out the [Windows Media Player Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bb383953(v=vs.90)).
If you need more information specific to implementation, you should take a look at [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/embedding-the-windows-media-player-control-in-a-c--solution).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are lacking some research. I recommend you first read this article [Adding Multimedia to an Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bb383899(v=vs.90)) and then see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/bb383953(v=vs.90)) and if you face any errors or problem, feel free to share with us.